# Excel Macro to run the output of an AS400 query

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-midrange

I have a spreadsheet that requires an output from an AS400 query with the updates details.  The only change to the query that is run is the specified date range (which is typically the current date).

I am happy to update and refresh the query each time on AS400 to ensure the date is up to date, however i was hoping it would be possible to tie in a macro on Excel that would run through the data import method (e.g. select the query, log in with username/password).  This would allow a press of a button for the data to refresh on the specified tab.

Would this be possible, or is it better to be left as a manual task?

Thanks

Comment: There's certainly an ODBC provider for it. Use that through ADODB and send a parameterized query to the server. Your question is way too broad to be answerable in any more specific way.

Answer (score 0):

change your query using WRKQRY and define the date as CURRENT(DATE)